# How can I get shared secret in hexadecimal format?

Tags: c++, openssl

So, I have code, like this:

```
#include <openssl/dh.h>
#include <iostream>
const char* userA_PrivateKey = "6e11 ...
const char* userA_PublicKey = "365b ...
const char* userB_PublicKey = "16db ...
const char* p = "00a7 ...
const char* g = "2";


int main()
{

    DH* dh = DH_new();

    BN_dec2bn(&dh->g, g);
    BN_hex2bn(&dh->p, p);
    BN_hex2bn(&dh->priv_key, userA_PrivateKey);

    BIGNUM* pubKeyUserB = NULL;
    BN_dec2bn(&pubKeyUserB, userB_PublicKey);

    //Compute the shared secret
    int secret_size;
    unsigned char* secret;
    //
    int dhSize = DH_size(dh);
    //
    secret = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(OPENSSL_malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * dhSize));

    if (0 > (secret_size = DH_compute_key(secret, pubKeyUserB, dh)))
    {
        std::cerr << "Error[33]!\n", -1;
    }

    std::cout << '\n' << secret << '\n';

    return 0;

}
```

But in output i get this:
[image]

How can I get in output hexadecimal secret in ANSI string?
(I really hope in secret lies what I need, not a garbage or something)

Comment: You know the length of the data in the "string" (`dhSize`), so just iterate over each and every byte and display it in any format you wish.

Comment: Why are you `const_cast`ing from `void*` to `void*`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I got a bigger string, but it still hieroglyphs

Comment: `std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << static_cast<int>(my_byte_value);` That cast is very important, since otherwise the code will output any kind of `char` as a character.

Answer (score 0):

So, solution is

```
std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << static_cast<int>(my_byte_value);
```

(thanks to @Someprogrammerdude)